# Laravel Listener not fired even though the event was triggered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-events

I am developing a web application using Laravel framework. I am trying to trying to use event and listener in my application. But the event was trigged and the listener for the trigged event is not fired.

This is my controller action

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //other code
        $item = Item::create($request->all())
        broadcast(new ItemCreated($item));
        return "Item created successfully";
    }
```

This is my Events\ItemCreated.php

```
class ItemCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $item;

    public function __construct($item)
    {
        $this->item = $item;
    }
}
```

Then I have a listener for that event.

Listeners/EmailSubscribedUsers.php

```
class EmailSubscribedUsers
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //this constructor is not triggered
    }


    public function handle(ItemCreated $event)
    {
        //This method is not fired
    } 
}
```

In the EventServiceProvider I registered the event and the listener like this

```
protected $listen = [

    ItemCreated::class => [
        EmailSubscribedUsers::class
    ]
];
```

The event is trigged. But the listener is not fired. Why? What is wrong?

I tried the following solutions.

```
php artisan optimize
composer dumpautoload
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Comment: What version are you running?  optimize and clear-compiled haven't been used in a while.

Comment: Latest Laravel (5.7).

Comment: I'm guessing your actual code differs from what you've posted. For example, is your listener `queueable`? If yes, did you run `artisan queue:work`?

Comment: My sense is that if you post your `real` code, we may be able to help

Comment: `broadcast()` shouldn't be `event()`?

Comment: That is the real code. So empty coz I am trying the event and the listener

Comment: Hmm, so your listener doesnt implement ShouldQueue?

Comment: No. I does not.

Comment: I tried using event() as well. Not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry everyone. The issue was I was unit testing. In the unit testing if I used Event::fake(), the event listeners are not triggered. I wanted to tested the logic in the event listeners. Therefore, I removed the Event::fake() and tested the logic in the listener instead.

Answer (score 4):

First of all as pointed in comments use

```
event(new ItemCreated($item));
```

and not

```
broadcast(new ItemCreated($item));
```

In addition make sure you have set `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `sync` in your `.env` file. If you used some other connection (for example `database` or `Redis`) make sure you run in console command:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

The last thing - verify your error log in `storage/logs` directory. You might have some other errors (for example missing import) and that's why your listener fails.

Also make sure in `EventServiceProvider` that you use valid classes and imported valid namespaces - otherwise listener won't be triggered.

Comment: Actually the listener is fired. It is just not fired in the unit test.

Comment: @WaiYanHein Well, you haven't mentioned that in your question. How do you know it's not fired? Do you know that in `phpunit.xml` there might be different driver set for queues? How your test look like?

Comment: I will post my test later

Comment: QUEUE_CONNECTION to sync solve my problem